# maven release plugin: releasing from git sub folder?

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-central

When I try to do a release from a git repository clone's sub folder, ie. "/abc", the release plugin changes the developerConnection from "...:repo.git" to "...:repo.git/abc" which is obviously nonsensical.

How do I prevent this from happening?

The project in question can be found here: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/misc

I also posted the detailed workaround there.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround, I set the release plugin's pushChanges option to false and do a manual "git push --tags; git push --all" after preparing the release. On top of that, I fix the scm.url in release.properties before running "mvn release:perform".